# Why does HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest function make an error when it gets an instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

According to some samples in the internet and [this guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7148.websockets-in-asp-net.aspx) I created a connection of webSocket .

```
public class sockets: IHttpHandler {

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest) {
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new socketHandler());
        }
    }
}

public class socketHandler: WebSocketHandler {

    public socketHandler(): base(null) {}
}
```

There is an error in the line-

```
context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new socketHandler());
```

the error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'socketHandler' to
>   'System.Func(System.Web.WebSockets.AspNetWebSocketContext,System.Threading.Tasks.Task)'

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

The `AcceptWebSocketRequest` takes a method as argument, not a class instance. You code should look something like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    if (context.IsWebSocketRequest) {
        context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(HandleWebSocket);
    }
}

private Task HandleWebSocket(WebSocketContext wsContext)
{
    // Do something useful
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping..then the sample in the guide i linked to was wrong? however, in the socketHandler class I implemented the OnOpen, OnMessage etc functions...Now i dont understand when those functions will happen? and more important, when would the onOpen function in the javascript  happen?

Comment: You should take a look at this SO question, one of the answers might suite your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668398/using-websockets-with-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing a function from System.Web while attempting to use a function from Microsoft.Web.WebSockets.
Add the appropriate reference and it will work.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  The tutorial didn't seem to have a code download.  This really helped me resolve the issue