# Websocket server on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, websocket

I'm trying to host a websockets server on Azure. I'm a bit confused and was hoping you could help me.

I've followed many articles but my code is close to the one from this article : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessWS);
    }
}

public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

private async Task ProcessWS(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
{
    try
    {
        WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;
        while (true)
        {
            var url = context.RequestUri;
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                string userMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count)
                                            .Trim(new char[] { ' ' }); // We remove the spaces before and after
                // DO SOMETHING
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Info("Exception" + e.Message + " >>>" + e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

This works fine, I'm able to get the messages from my devices and answer to them.

But in some cases I need to send a message to another device, example :

DEVICE A sends "Tell Device B to blink"

Since it's a websockets server and Device B has already talked with the server I should have somewhere a connection opened with Device B. And when Device A asks me for it I can send a message to Device B.

But how can I achieve that with my code ? How can I find the connection to device B ? If not possible how should I do it ?

I hope my problem is described enough to be understood.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how can I achieve that with my code ? How can I find the connection to device B ? If not possible how should I do it ?

According to your scenario, I followed this tutorial about  [webapi-and-websockets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2012/07/17/building-real-time-web-apps-with-asp-net-webapi-and-websockets/) and implement [my Web API project](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspNet-WebAPI-websockets) that could establish connection between clients. Here is the screenshoot for test, you could refer to it:

[image]

Additionally, you could leverage [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) and map your client (user) to signalR connections. For more details, you could refer to [Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections). Also, you could refer to the git sample [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Samples](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/release/samples/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Samples).

**UPDATE:**

> How would you use signalR in that case ?

For a simple way, we could retain connection and user info stored in memory, For more details, you could refer to [In-memory storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#in-memory-storage). Based on this scenario, I wrote a sample project [AspDotNet-SignalR-Chat](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspDotNet-SignalR-Chat), you could refer to it, and here is the screenshot for test:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! However do you think it's ok to use Microsoft.Websockets since it's not developed anymore ?

Comment: At least, it could work for now and it could meet the requirement. For long consideration,  I recommend you using SignalR.

Comment: How would you use signalR in that case ? According to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668398/using-websockets-with-asp-net-web-api
it's not possible to inherit from the WebSocketHandler of SignalR

Comment: Use `WebSocketHandler` is used to handle the websocket processing by yourself. While use SignalR, you need to follow the feature provided by it. I updated my answer for your question, you could refer to it.